# Disable second monitor

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I have dual-monitors, both on a single GPU. At times I don't use the second one, particularly in GPU-intensive gaming - is it possible to disable the monitor so that the GPU doesn't have to render those pixels?

Comment: Disconnect it from that GPU!!!

Comment: Yeah, I'm ***totally*** going to plug in and unplug my monitor every time I tab out of a game....

Comment: you can always enable/disable monitors from the Screen resolution applet. in the Multiple monitors dropdown, select "Show desktop only on X" where X is the ID of the monitor you what to keep enabled. to resume dual screen, select "Extend these Displays".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to switch to "Computer only" OR "Extend" mode.

[image]

Comment: I will test today and accept if works correctly, though this seems like the most obvious and reliable answer.